# Problema para mostrar un formulario con select

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

Hola estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar el formulario por medio del select seleccionado con registro de mi bd lo verifico con un console.log y el resultado es vacío anexo código.

**Select**

```
   <label class="label">Metodo de Pago</label>
   <div class="control">
       <div class="select">
          <select id="metodoPago" name="id_metodo_pago" onchange="mostrarFormulario()">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Una Opción:</option>
                <?php
                  $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM metodo_pago ORDER BY id_metodo_pago");
                  while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $linea['id_metodo_pago'] ;?>"><?php echo $linea['metodo_pago'] ;?></option>
                <?php
                  }
                ?>
           </select>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Formulario**

```
<form id="formEfectivo" style="display: none;">
        <label for="montoEfectivo">Monto en Efectivo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="montoEfectivo">
    </form>


    <form id="formTransferencia" style="display: none;">
        <label for="montoTransferencia">Monto en Transferencia:</label>
        <input type="text" id="montoTransferencia">
</form>
```

**function mostrarFormulario**

```
<script>
   function mostrarFormulario() {
    var metodoPago = document.getElementById("metodoPago");
    var opcionSeleccionada = metodoPago.value;
    console.log("Opción seleccionada: " + opcionSeleccionada);

    if (opcionSeleccionada === "1") {
        document.getElementById("formEfectivo").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("formTransferencia").style.display = "none";
    } else if (opcionSeleccionada === "2") {
        document.getElementById("formEfectivo").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("formTransferencia").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

no veo que tengas conectado la base de datos pero supondria que lo hiciste, probe tu codigo y me fue bien, tal vez el id de los metodos de paga no estan siendo extraidos de la BD o directamente no tienes id de metodos de pago, prueba con hacer un

`echo $linea["id_metodos_pago"];`

si no te aparece nada ahí tienes el problema

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración el echo me muestra perfectamente el id seleccionado creo que el problema lo tengo en la función (mostrarFormulario), la conexión la tengo perfectamente lo que pasa es que no puse todo para no alargar la pregunta, mi tabla metodo_pago es: id_metodo_pago, metodo_pago por lo cual los valores se me reflejan perfectamente en el select, pero de verdad no entiendo en que esta fallando mi función

Comment: disculpa no poder ayudarte, estudiare más, igual yo probe tu codigo copiandolo y si me aparecia en consola lo que se iba seleccionando, espero puedas resolver saludos!